# What percent of internet users use mouse back/forward versus the browser back/forward buttons?

Tags: interface, input, mouse

I personally almost never use the browser buttons and I imagine it's the same for most tech savvy users but I want to know what the usage patterns are like for the rest of the population. From my own observation (a very small sample) older people, and non-tech savvy tend to click the browser buttons. It amazes me that there are still many mice on the market that don't have back/forward buttons. Are the any studies on this?

Comment: Hi @guesst, welcome to the community! It'll be great co-learning experience for others if you can provide more context around how this information will be used in designing interactions. For e.g. are you pondering between having explicit back/ forward buttons vs letting the user figure it out themselves etc.

Comment: After 30+ years of using a computer I consider myself relatively "tech savvy" and hopefully not yet in your "older people" category. I don't use back buttons on my mouse, and any mice I own which have such buttons they get disabled really quickly. They get pressed accidentally far too often for my liking, and depending on the site I am on may lose all sorts of important input. I use buttons on screen, or keyboard shortcuts if and when I want to go back or forward through the history for a tab. And given how often I open new tabs from links, many of my tabs have no "back" to go to anyway.

Comment: 29 year old here. I develop, design, game, and been the computer guy of my family since we first bought a gateway in the 90's, and absolutely never have used my mouse back/forward buttons and avoid any mice that I can't deactivate that functionality on. I guess it could just be a preference thing.